# Insert additional condition into IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have the following IF statement, which is correct and working, but I need to add another IF statement to it to state: where cells M17+18 = 0 to then set this to "" (blank) where applicable. Then if the cells combined do not equal `0` to return the VLOOKUP shown. This is quite large already so I'm not sure where to put it.

```
=IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False)),"",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False))=0,"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False)),"",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False)))
```

Comment: What are you unsure about exactly? About how an `If()` should be structured in an Excel formula?

Comment: So search the correct "otherwise" part and add your new if. Without more information about your data and where to put it exactly it's unlikely you get any help. For example to answer your problem I could just say: Put `IF(SUM($M$17;$M$18)=0;"";your vlookup)` into A1.

Comment: My apologies. I have specified a number of work arounds to cleanse the data, for example if it is not there etc then N/A else if the vlookup returns a 0 to blank that. I also need to specify at some point in the above formula ALSO where the cells m17+18=0 then set this to blank"".

Comment: My problem is I want to add the additional part tot he above but am not too sure where to add it to. It is not as simple as me addignt he above after the comma unfortunately. i PRESUME i WOULD NEED SOMETHING LIKE =IF(IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False)),"",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False))=0,"",
IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False)),"",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False))M17+M18=0,",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,False))

Comment: Maybe AND() helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer (but without being quite sure what is required):

```
 =IF(OR(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,0)),VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,0)=0,M17+M18=0),"",VLOOKUP($B$6&D9,'Data-Figure'!$A:$Q,10,0))
```